# Standard way to loop through list of items in foreach

Tags: c#, foreach

A small question.

Which is the better way to loop, or are they both the same.

APPROACH 1:

```
foreach(var listitem in GetItems())
{
}
```

APPROACH 2:

```
var listItems = GetItems();

foreach(var listitem in listItems)
{
}

private List<myclass> GetItems()
{
  //get items from database
}
```

I could find no difference in the execution time in my case, but then there were only a few hundred records in the database.

I would like to know, in approach 1, will it execute `GetItems()`, for each item in the list, or does it happen just once.

Comment: Both of them are equal. You use second approach if you want to use `listItems` at multiple places so that you don't need to call the method multiple times.

Comment: They are the same. No, of course, it will not execute every time. It will be compiled into one `GetItems` call and one `while` block.

Comment: `GetItems()` would execute only once. I would recommend the first approach because second approach creates and holds an object `listItems` with lifetime of whole method. It would get garbage collected only when CLR calls it or explicitly invoked in code.

Comment: "better" is in the eye of the beholder. There is no practical difference between the two options, and after the JIT compiler's done with the code, there may not even be _any_ difference (i.e. the compiled native code may be identical). See marked duplicate for some insight into this primarily opinion based question.

Answer (score -1):

In Approach 1, the method 'GetItems()' will be executed only once. If you try to debug the foreach loop code you can actually see it yourself.

Comment: Both will only execute that method call once

Comment: that is obvious thing. even in approach 2 it will get executed only 1 time.

Comment: Why the downvote ? The question was asked about approach 1 and I was to the point. I am not bothered about the points, If you really think this answer is not correct, kindly explain what you think the answer is ? or alteast justify your point.

Comment: Read the question carefully again. _I would like to know, in approach 1, will it execute GetItems(), for each item in the list, or does it happen just once_ .I hope this is the question ? OP already knew approach 2 executed only once. He wants to know whether approach 1 also did the same ?